# How to force JPG export using Timthumb.php?

Tags: php, wordpress

Timthumb, the popular image resize/crop script (http://code.google.com/p/timthumb/) keeps the same format of the original image.

How can I force the output to be JPG, independently from the original format?

Comment: Did you try taking the result image and save it as jpg? might be easier.

Comment: The solution: http://o7.no/Kp9xF7 (I used screenshot because I can't insert code in comments)

Comment: If this is a working solution publish is as an answer and accept it.